# Retrive an array stored in a cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

I have a cookie that I created in JQuery like this :

```
var tmzoffset = "+03:00"; 
var txtlocation= "Etc/UTC"; 
var IP = "166.166.166.166"; 
$.cookie("user", [tmzoffset,txtlocation,IP]);
```

now I would like to extract each item from the array stored in that cookie and store them in other seperate variables , Please how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's stored as a comma seperated string, as cookies can't contain arrays, so if you split on comma, you'll have the array you put in back again (assuming you did'nt have commas in your values, which you don't):

```
var arr = $.cookie("user").split(',');

var tmzoffset = arr[0];
var txtlocation= arr[1];
var IP = arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON to serialize and parse your object:

```
$.cookie("user", JSON.stringify([tmzoffset,txtlocation,IP]));

var array = JSON.parse($.cookie("user"));
```

Support is built into modern browsers, but see http://json.org for a fallback script for older ones (IE).